# jquery datepicker issues with month and year dropdown on a blockUI popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery date picker plugin for my application and strangely it does not show the drop downs after i have attached it in a form element and the entire process above happens in a block UI popup component

It does not work despite mentioning change month and change Year to true this is the code i have written and after clicking on the select box the drop down does not appear

```
$("#dateFrom").datepicker({
  yearRange: '1900:2030',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  minDate: new Date(),
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

some one please help me

Comment: Make sure you don't have another element with same `#dateFrom` id.. that would cause the dialog not to show up..

Comment: I don't have one more . I get the entire date picker component visible, only the select drop downs doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try with this instead

```
$( "#datetextbox" ).datepicker({  

   //set true to show months  
            changeMonth: true,  

            //set true to show year  
   changeYear: true,  

           //set date for date range  
    minDate: new Date(2012,1,23),  
            maxDate: new Date(2013,1,26),  

           //set if you want icon to be visible  
   showOn: "button",  
   buttonImage: "/images/cal.gif",  
   buttonImageOnly: true  
       });
```

Comment: do we need to specify any extra attributes while rendering  this particular on a Jquery BlockUI ?